# Odata override behaviour of orderby

Tags: sql, odata

My date column in sql table can be null, so I getting that data using OData but if I order it by asc, null values is in front of all other rows. I want that it be desplayed after all others:

```
 1. 31.12.2000
 2. 31.12.2010
 3. null
```

Is there is possibility to somehow override filtering so it take null value as may be DateTime.MaxValue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ANSI standard supports `NULLS FIRST` and `NULLS LAST`, but SQL Server does not have these options.

Instead, you can use two keys in the `ORDER BY`:

```
order by (case when col is not null then 1 else 2 end),
         col asc
```

Comment: Not exactly what I need. Here [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309461(v=crm.7).aspx#BKMK_orderby) is example of orderby what I using <br/>`/AccountSet?$select=Address1_Country,Address1_City,Name&$orderby=Address1_Country asc&$filter=(Address1_Country ne null) and (Address1_City ne null)` .<br/> So how to change $orderby=Address1_Country asc, so null values go to end of queue.

Comment: As there is no other suggestion, I will mark that one as correct, as it is pointed to another solution of my problem. However I did update DB and changed null to DateTime.MaxValue so ordering can be done with OData orderby property.